# Why is \tex_par:D behaving differently from \par?

Tags: lists, indentation, expl3

As illustrated in the MWE, using `\tex_par:D` rather than `\par` within a `list` environment leads to unexpected side-effects. Is this intended behavior? If so, it's likely to break a lot of code. I ran across this issue trying to use the current version of `lipsum`, which uses the `expl3` version, within KOMA-Script's `addmargin` environment, and any other environment that uses the same list trick is going to be broken in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mypar} {} {\tex_par:D}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill
\begin{list}{}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{2cm}
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{2cm}
  }
 \item Here's a paragraph with enough text that we can see where the line wraps.

 Here's another paragraph after a traditional paragraph break. This is fine.

 Now we'll end this one with the expl3 version to see what happens next.\mypar
 And here's a forth to see where we are. The left and right margins are now disregarded.\par

 And they don't come back.
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in this output:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't par has a special meaning inside lists? Thus the inserted mypar is different from the normal par inside lists.

Comment: Yes, `\list` calls `\@trivlist` which uses `\@setpar` to redefine `\par`. The definition of `\mypar` or `\tex_par:D` is never changed, though, thus the different results

Comment: OK, so now I understand why it's happening. I'm still curious as to whether this is an intentional design decision. The interface3 documentation urges us to avoid calling primitives directly, but this sort of issue suggests we can't safely do that because we can't predict the interactions (like lipsum + addmargin) that users will create, which can mean expl3 code gets called in contexts where the `:D` instructions don't have the meaning they should.

Comment: `\cs_new:Npn \latex_par: { \par }`

Comment: @HenriMenke Ah yes, you are right.

Comment: From my understanding, the `\tex_XXX` commands are there to keep the original *meaning* of TeX primitives in case they are needed for later use. If this is the case, the above behavior is expected. You can still always define macros, that just expand to the original primitive name which then has either the original or new meaning. Note the difference between `\let` and `\def` in defining new commands here.

Comment: @siracusa That's what I had gathered after this discussion. Of course if you're interacting with LaTeX code, you probably really don't want the unaltered TeX primitive \par, do you? Since \par can be redefined, trying to use \tex_par:D is highly likely to result in this sort of undesired behavior.

Comment: There are situations where a copy of the original version comes in handy. Think of local/boxed environments like minipages, verbatim code or whatever, where you really don't want a modified version. Plain TeX already had such a copy, `\endgraf`, for similar purposes.